# Add fancy scroll bar on Tag-input autocomplete list

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, autocomplete, ng-tags-input

I want to add fancy scroll bar on tag-input autocomplete (Angular 1.x) list.

I used slimScroll library for scroll bar. But the problem is that if i added the slimScroll then it is not working because autocomplete list come after DOM load.

I tried to add the slimScroll during fetching record for autocomplete. but its not working there.

I tried the scrollbar using css but its not working in **Firefox**.

Any idea, How to implement the scrollbar for tag-input autocomplete result.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery plugins, css custom scroll bar is not browser compatible solution.
Try: [Link1](https://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/demo/basic.html) or [Link2](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html)

Comment: I already used JQuery plugin (Slim scroll bar) but its not working with autocomplete list. if i try to add the jquery slimscroll during autocomplete result then its hang my browser. (Because it load the script every time due to autocomplete list).